# Как запустить приложение node.js в браузере?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Как запустить приложение, что бы результат отобразился в браузере?

Установил этот npm-пакет [node-whois](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-whois). Если в консоли ввести node `app.js`, то работает:

[image: Node.js]

Как сделать так, чтобы результат работы этого скрипта отображался не в консоли, а в браузере? Типа вот этого:

[image: Node.js]

Comment: Попробуй заменить `console.log` на `process.stdout.write`

Comment: Код своего `app.js` покажите для начала.

Comment: @sergey-rufanov 
`var whois = require('node-whois')
whois.lookup('google.com', function (err, data) {
  console.log(data)
})`

Comment: @Greyson `process.stdout.write` не работает?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это не то, на втором скрине я лишь привел пример чего я хочу. В итоге мне нужно сделать так, что бы на html странице я мог в input вписать имя домена и это значение передалось в app.js. Т.е. как я могу подключить app.js к index.html? Если напрямую подключать `<script src="app.js"></script>`, то выдает ошибку _Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined_, что логично.

Comment: Это же вам не просто `javascript`, который можно включить через  `src="app.js"`  Это ж СЕРВЕРНЫЙ язык однако))  Чтоб он обработал данные с формы..нужно в начале в `html` сделать форму (form) и отправить их на сервер (submit), а на сервере обрабатывать данные......может это поможет как пример: http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-and-handling-forms-in-node-js/

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я понимаю что это серверный язык, просто ни разу еще не работал с nodejs. Ссылка помогла, это то что я искал, спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас консольное приложение. Вам же нужно сделать из него веб-приложение, которое будет обрабатывать запросы браузера. В самом простом варианте, это выглядит как-то так(с использованием [Express](http://expressjs.com/)):

```
var express = require('express');
var whois = require('node-whois');

var app = express();
var port = 8080;

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.contentType('text/plain');

    whois.lookup('google.com', function(err, data) {
        res.send(data)
    });
});

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('server running at http://localhost:%s', port);
});
```

Исходная задача выполненна - ура!

Однако на деле этого мало. Вскоре вам захочется увидеть некую веб-страничку, на которой можно было бы ввести домен, нажать кнопку, и ответом получить не вот такую кучу информации в текстовом виде, а лишь некоторые, наиболее интересные конечному пользователю данные..

Для этого вам уже приведется изучить хотя бы базовые навыки верстки, а так-же освоить тот-же Express для написания бекенда.